# Is there any way to customise variant managment in SmartTable in worklist fiori app?

Tags: sapui5

i'm using worklist app and in smartTable i'm using variant management. i want to customise variant managment so as it can also store variants of other control say, smartfilterbar. Or binding whole page in one variant management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SmartVariantManagement control to have one Variant Management for Table and Filterbar: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/b1d4d261524b4a3da78547ed4283a082